# How can I access to e.handled for a button in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, code-behind

I have some buttons in master page (`mainpage`) and I use the event click of its in other page by `map` like:

```
MainPage mp = (MainPage)(((BusinessApplication8.Controls.BusyIndicator)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content);
```

it's being run more than one and I can not use a `e.Handdled` to prevent them.
How can I do to control it?

for example we want our code inside below event(`ListPish_Emza_Click`) runs only once per click :

```
void ListPish_Emza_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (sender == e.OriginalSource)
        return;
    Approve_Click(sender, e);

}
```

but above code runs more than one per click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firing an event manually is not recommended approach.

I can't realize your application architecture. But, you should put your code in a method in static class and use it.

Comment: thanks, Is there any way for firing an event automatically? Could you put an example about that?

Comment: Why do you write this code?

MainPage mp = (MainPage)(((BusinessApplication8.Controls.BusyIndicator)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content);